# How to make each value of a data set a different marker?

Tags: plotting, graphics, marker

I have multiple data lists on a ListLogPlot. There are 8 data lists and each data list has 6 {x,y} points, and I want each point to have a different marker, on the same plot. Is this possible?

My code so far is as below:

```
Plot1 = {{2.10013, 0.0000100688}, {2.10013, 4.89108*10^-8}, {2.10013, 1.15283*10^-8}, {2.10013, 6.04358*10^-9}, {2.10013, 2.96581*10^-9}, {2.10013, 1.7618*10^-9}}
Plot2 ={{0.9758, 7.64394*10^-6}, {0.9758, 2.19517*10^-8}, {0.9758, 7.62142*10^-9}, {0.9758, 3.1309*10^-9}, {0.9758, 1.6758*10^-9}, {0.9758, 1.18639*10^-9}}
Plot3 = {{2.552, 0.0000124046}, {2.552, 9.67008*10^-8}, {2.552, 3.49325*10^-8}, {2.552, 1.61281*10^-8}, {2.552, 8.06587*10^-9}, {2.552, 3.43834*10^-9}}
Plot4 = {{4.203, 0.0000239139}, {4.203, 2.27623*10^-7}, {4.203, 1.67293*10^-8}, {4.203, 7.8656*10^-9}, {4.203, 4.97852*10^-9}, {4.203, 2.68124*10^-9}}
Plot5 =  {{1.882, 0.000011998}, {1.882, 5.47129*10^-8}, {1.882, 2.08299*10^-8}, {1.882, 1.09622*10^-8}, {1.882, 6.40376*10^-9}, {1.882, 3.50434*10^-9}}
Plot6 = {{5.042, 0.0000227577}, {5.042, 7.73744*10^-8}, {5.042, 2.61552*10^-8}, {5.042, 1.39492*10^-8}, {5.042, 7.96422*10^-9}, {5.042, 5.15056*10^-9}}
Plot7 = {{6.205, 0.0000575172}, {6.205, 3.19688*10^-7}, {6.205, 1.16727*10^-7}, {6.205, 5.97103*10^-8}, {6.205, 2.88467*10^-8}, {6.205, 1.37238*10^-8}}
Plot8 = {{3.743, 0.0000176255}, {3.743, 7.67293*10^-8}, {3.743, 2.6812*10^-8}, {3.743, 1.45814*10^-8}, {3.743, 9.44051*10^-9}, {3.743, 6.23063*10^-9}}
Markers = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"};
ListLogPlot[{Plot1,Plot2,Plot3,Plot4,Plot5,Plot6,Plot7,Plot8}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Purple, Green, Orange, Magenta, Cyan, Pink}, PlotLegends -> {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
```

This shows my data lists on the plot fine, but when I add `PlotMarkers -> Markers` it sets Plot1 to a, Plot2 to b etc. Is there any way around this so that {2.10013, 0.0000100688} = a, {2.10013, 4.89108*10^-8} = b, and so on for each plot? **I.e. all the blue points below labelled a, b, c... red a, b ,c... etc**
[image]

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please load all the lists of data. The words "dataset" and "plot markers" have known meaning in Mathematica even if these are spelled a bit differently. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, I've edited to add the actual data to my post.

Comment: If I understand what you want, try transposing your data: `ListLogPlot[Transpose@ {Plot1, Plot2, Plot3, ...., Plot8}, <rest of your options>, PlotMarkers -> Markers]`.

Comment: Also, you could save yourself future grief by not capitalizing your variables and functions so they cannot get confused with MA commands. `Plot` and `Marker` is akin to asking for such trouble.

Comment: @MarcoB This works for the actual marker names themselves but changes the colours so that all the a values are blue, b values red etc. Rather than all of the Plot1 values being blue, and then marked. If that makes sense?

Comment: @Schaef I see. That sounds like it would require heavy manual intervention then. It may be easiest to just build up the plot by hand using Graphics.

Answer (score 1):

```
data[1] = {{2.10013, 0.0000100688}, {2.10013, 4.89108*10^-8}, {2.10013, 1.15283*10^-8}, {2.10013, 6.04358*10^-9}, {2.10013, 2.96581*10^-9}, {2.10013, 1.7618*10^-9}};
data[2] = {{0.9758, 7.64394*10^-6}, {0.9758, 2.19517*10^-8}, {0.9758, 7.62142*10^-9}, {0.9758, 3.1309*10^-9}, {0.9758, 1.6758*10^-9}, {0.9758, 1.18639*10^-9}};
data[3] = {{2.552, 0.0000124046}, {2.552, 9.67008*10^-8}, {2.552, 3.49325*10^-8}, {2.552, 1.61281*10^-8}, {2.552, 8.06587*10^-9}, {2.552, 3.43834*10^-9}};
data[4] = {{4.203, 0.0000239139}, {4.203, 2.27623*10^-7}, {4.203, 1.67293*10^-8}, {4.203, 7.8656*10^-9}, {4.203, 4.97852*10^-9}, {4.203, 2.68124*10^-9}};
data[5] = {{1.882, 0.000011998}, {1.882, 5.47129*10^-8}, {1.882, 2.08299*10^-8}, {1.882, 1.09622*10^-8}, {1.882, 6.40376*10^-9}, {1.882, 3.50434*10^-9}};
data[6] = {{5.042, 0.0000227577}, {5.042, 7.73744*10^-8}, {5.042, 2.61552*10^-8}, {5.042, 1.39492*10^-8}, {5.042, 7.96422*10^-9}, {5.042, 5.15056*10^-9}};
data[7] = {{6.205, 0.0000575172}, {6.205, 3.19688*10^-7}, {6.205, 1.16727*10^-7}, {6.205, 5.97103*10^-8}, {6.205, 2.88467*10^-8}, {6.205, 1.37238*10^-8}};
data[8] = {{3.743, 0.0000176255}, {3.743, 7.67293*10^-8}, {3.743, 2.6812*10^-8}, {3.743, 1.45814*10^-8}, {3.743, 9.44051*10^-9}, {3.743, 6.23063*10^-9}};
myMarkers = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"};

alldata = Array[data,8];

ListLogPlot[
Flatten[alldata,{2}]
, PlotStyle -> Array[Hue,Length[alldata],{0,0.9}]
, PlotLegends -> Range[Length[alldata]]
, PlotMarkers->myMarkers
]
```

[image]